# Unresponsive UITextField, second time view is presented

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

i have a UITextView which i create programmatically in the views viewDidLoad event.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    inputText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 90, 290, 150)];

    [inputText.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [inputText.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [inputText.layer setBorderWidth: 3.0f];
    [inputText.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [inputText.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [inputText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

    [self.view addSubview:inputText];

}
```

This works fine, the first time the view is presented, but the second time it is presented, the UITextView is unresponsive to touches, the keyboard does not popup.

This is how i direct to the view.

someotherView.m

```
-(IBAction)insertToTable:(id)sender {

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"insertSegue" sender:self];
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Full code:

.h
    @interface ViewControllerInsert : UIViewController
    {
        UITextView *inputText;
        UISegmentedControl *experienceValue;
    }

```
- (IBAction)InsertAction:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *experienceValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *inputText;

@end
```

.m

other then the code i linked above, this is all there is

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**EDIT 2**

Found the issue, this was coused by the Animation i used? Very odd, i was using Flip Vertically, but when i swapped to default, it worked perfectly ?

Comment: No i havnt, and there is no code in viewWillAppear

Comment: Just tried, same issue

Comment: Show your full code .h and .m